# is there a way to highlight the only the selected Item in angular nested tree view?

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to build a treeview in my angular project from a nested data and i want to highlight only the selected item.
Here is the stackblitz link what i had tried.
https://angular-ivy-wcv63x.stackblitz.io

currently it highlights all the selected items and turns off on isitemSelected == false

please suggest/help, if there are any missing elements in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we want to "only select one" we use a simple variable and store the value, not use a property of the "item" or an array.

```
itemSelected:any=null
```

And use ngClass as

```
<div class="treeView" (click)="onexpand(item)"  
      [ngClass]="{'treeViewSelected': item==itemSelected, 
                  'treeViewExpanded': item.isExpanded}">
    ...
</div>
```

As the "itemSelected" it's only one, you need the itemSelected belong to "parent". So we are using a itemSelected itemSelectedChange. As we have a recursive element, we need emit also the value to the "parent". So really the itemSelect will be, an `@Input`, an `@Ouput` and a `getter` to emit the value. Some like

```
  _itemSelected: any = null;
  @Input('itemSelected') set _(value: any) {
    this._itemSelected = value;
  }
  get itemSelected() {
    return this._itemSelected;
  }
  set itemSelected(value: any) {
    this._itemSelected = value;
    this.itemSelectedChange.emit(value);
  }
  @Output() itemSelectedChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And change the onexpand using emit

```
  onexpand(item) {
    this.itemSelectedChange.emit(item == this.itemSelected ? null : item);

    if (item.expanded) {
      item.expanded = !item.expanded;
      return;
    } else {
      if (item.children) {
        if (item.children.length > 0) {
          item.expanded = true;
        } else {
          item.expanded = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now we are using two ways binding.

In app.component

```
itemSelected:any=null
//and

<app-tree [items]="sampleData" [(itemSelected)]="itemSelected"></app-tree>
```

In the recursive component

```
<ul class="tree-view">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    ...
    <ul *ngIf="item.children && item.expanded">
      <!--here use the two binding too-->
      <app-tree [items]="item.children" [(itemSelected)]="itemSelected">
      </app-tree>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfgpds?file=src%2Ftree%2Ftree.component.ts,src%2Ftree%2Ftree.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)